# Fill array out with loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Hi i have been trying to use a for loop to print out 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

```
int[] numbers = new int[7];

for (int i = 7; i < numbers.Length; i--)
        {
            numbers[i] = i - 1;
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
        }
```

Also been trying to use a while look to print out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

```
int[] numbers2 = new int[7];
int j = 1;

while (j > numbers2.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
            j++;
        }
```

Somebody that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: `for (int i = numbers.Length -1; i >= 0; i--) {numbers[i] = i + 1; Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[7];

for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
{
    numbers[i - 1] = i;
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i - 1]);
}
```

Since you are going `down` you must also modify your loop condition to stop when i gets too low, 0 in this case.

You can also iterate over reversed range:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Reverse();
foreach (var number in range)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Or using while:

```
var currentNumber = 7;
while (currentNumber > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentNumber--);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course with using break points and trace your code step by step, you can find the misbehaved parts of your code easily. 
In this way you can learn new things instead of solving just your problems.
I think the below link will help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019